# Searching a unit square with a point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, vector-analysis

For motivation, imagine a pair of analog dials that turn continuously from 0 to 1 - how can you turn those dials in such a search pattern, that eventually every pair of possible dial positions is visited?

Let us define $T$ as the set of real numbers greater or equal to 0.

Let us define $U$ as the set of real numbers between 0 and 1, inclusive.

Let's say that a function, $f(x)$, is *pretty* if all of:

- is a unary function
- has a domain of $T$
- has a range of $U$
- is continuous
- is differentiable.

For example, $(sin(x)+1)\over 2$, is pretty.

Does there exist a pair of pretty functions, $p$ and $q$, such that for any two elements of $U$, $a$ and $b$, there exists some element of $T$, t, such that both $p(t) = a$ and $q(t) = b$ ?

If yes, what is one such pair of functions?

if not, whats a sketch of a proof?

Comment: So, the map $t \mapsto (p(t), q(t))$ is a space-filling curve. The wikipedia article states that those cannot be differentiable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve#Properties (without any reference, though)

Comment: @lisyarus, apparently the proof is pretty hard https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201424/proof-that-no-differentiable-space-filling-curve-exists